# What's the point of the "unadvertised" sale in the episode "The Pie"?

Tags: plot-explanation, seinfeld

In the Seinfeld episode "The Pie", a saleswoman tells George that the store is having an upcoming "unadvertised" sale, in which a suit normally out of his price range would cost much less.

But I don't quite understand what was going on in this scene. What would a store gain by having a sale they don't intend to inform the public about? And why would she tell George anyway? Was there anything more to this unadvertized sale?

Comment: If you are asking about the marketing point of view, then maybe https://money.stackexchange.com/ is the place to ask...

Comment: I tried to reword it more into an actual *Seinfeld* question rather than a general marketing question.

Comment: This reminds me of an episode of 'Curb Your Enthusiasm' (another Larry David show) in which Ted Danson donates anonymously to a museum but tells everyone about it and is therefore perceived as both humble *and* generous; The sale is obviously advertized because the saleswoman won't shut up about it, but it draws people's attention because it's *perceived* as an exciting secret nevertheless.